# How to merge properties within an array of objects based on specific property

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to merge related objects in an array of objects based on similar properties in a specific object key "name".

I have tried the following code but did not work:

```js
const students = [];

const obj = [{
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "4p",
    "mat": "80",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "4886",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": "39"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mtu Bure",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "3L",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "86",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "75",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Mtu Bure",
    "adm": "9790",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "77",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": "76"
  }
];

const groupedData = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const name = cur.name;
  if (!acc[name]) {
    acc[name] = {};
  }

  for (const key in cur) {
    acc[name][key] = cur[key];
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(groupedData);

const jsonObject = JSON.stringify(result);

const div = document.getElementById("students");

const span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = jsonObject;

div.appendChild(span);
```

```html
<div id="students">
</div>
```

Help me get the desired output as shown below;

```
[
    {
      "name": "A. Nasila",
      "adm": "4886",
      "class": "4p",
      "mat": "80",
      "eng": "75",
      "kis": "39"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mtu Bure",
      "adm": "9790",
      "class": "3L",
      "mat": "77",
      "eng": "86",
      "kis": "76"
    }
]
```

Comment: You are overwriting every key on each iteration even if it is an empty string, so it will simply keep the last object by name. You need to check if the value is empty before setting it. `for (const key in cur) { if (acc[name][key] === undefined || acc[name][key] === "") acc[name][key] = cur[key]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use **??=** operator ( [Nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) )

```js
const obj = 
  [ { name: 'A. Nasila', adm: '',     class: '4p', mat: '80', eng: '',   kis: ''   } 
  , { name: 'A. Nasila', adm: '4886', class: '',   mat: '',   eng: '',   kis: '39' } 
  , { name: 'Mtu Bure',  adm: '',     class: '3L', mat: '',   eng: '86', kis: ''   } 
  , { name: 'A. Nasila', adm: '',     class: '',   mat: '',   eng: '75', kis: ''   } 
  , { name: 'Mtu Bure',  adm: '9790', class: '',   mat: '77', eng: '',   kis: '76' } 
  ]; 

const res = Object.values(obj.reduce((r,o) =>
  {
  r[o.name] ??= {};
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => r[o.name][k] ||= o[k]);
  return r;
  }, {})); 

console.log( res )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: @Drarig29 That's **my** answer, so I'll use **my** indentation style.

Comment: @MisterJojo Fine 

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
const students = [];

const obj = [
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "4p",
    "mat": "80",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "4886",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": "39"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mtu Bure",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "3L",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "86",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "75",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Mtu Bure",
    "adm": "9790",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "77",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": "76"
  }
];

const groupedData = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const name = cur.name;
  if (!acc[name]) {
    acc[name] = {};
  }

  // Iterate through the keys of the current object and merge them
  for (const key in cur) {
    if (cur.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      acc[name][key] = cur[key] || acc[name][key];
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(groupedData);

const jsonObject = JSON.stringify(result);

const div = document.getElementById("students");

const span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = jsonObject;

div.appendChild(span);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Students</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="students">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

A little explanation of what's going on

First off, I used the reduce method to iterate through the array of objects (obj) and group them by the `name` property into the `groupedData` object.

If the `name` property is encountered for the first time, I then create a new object for it. If it has already been encountered, we merge the current object's properties into the existing object.

I then converted the `groupedData` object into an array of values using `Object.values` method.

EDIT: Made it work dynamically with all keys.

Comment: That is great! Is there a way to iterate through the code you've written inside if & else. Because am supposing it will be tiresome to use it on an object with many keys.

Comment: @AbednegoNasila I have updated my answer to match your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to iterate through the code you've written inside if & else. Because am supposing it will be tiresome to use it on an object with many keys.

- If you can assume they'll always be the same, you can hardcode them in a list.
- If you can assume they'll always be the same in the same array, but can't be hardcoded, use `Object.keys()` on the first object.

Then you can construct an object from an array of `[key, value]` tuples thanks to `Object.fromEntries()`.

You can't use the `??` operator for your values because you are using falsy values like empty strings.

```js
const keys = Object.keys(obj[0])

const result = Object.values(
  obj.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ({
      ...acc,
      [curr.name]: Object.fromEntries(
        keys.map((key) => [key, curr[key] || acc[curr.name]?.[key]])
      ),
    }),
    {}
  )
)
```

**PS:** In terms of performance, some other answers are a lot better than this one. But unless this code will be executed in a hot path of your application, there is no need to optimize this, and make your code unreadable.

Comment: If the `obj` array is very long, you might want to omit `name` from `keys`.

Comment: Well, if the OP really needs something optimized because it's a hot path of their application, they should not use my answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using spread, intermediate arrays, and getting full object data with `Object.entries()` for best performance.

It's also not clear what to do if 2 objects contain the same non-empty property, while I overwrite with the latest, Mister Jojo for example keeps the first one.

```js
console.log(
  obj.reduce((r, item, obj) => (
      (obj = r.map.get(item.name)) ? 
      Object.keys(item).forEach(k => k !== 'name' && item[k] && (obj[k] = item[k])) :
      r.map.set(item.name, r.arr[r.arr.length] = item) , r
    ), {arr: [], map: new Map}
  ).arr
);
```

```html
<script>
const obj = [{
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "4p",
    "mat": "80",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "4886",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": "39"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mtu Bure",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "3L",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "86",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "75",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Mtu Bure",
    "adm": "9790",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "77",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": "76"
  }
];
</script>
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000000">

const obj = [{
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "4p",
    "mat": "80",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "4886",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": "39"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mtu Bure",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "3L",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "86",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "A. Nasila",
    "adm": "",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "",
    "eng": "75",
    "kis": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Mtu Bure",
    "adm": "9790",
    "class": "",
    "mat": "77",
    "eng": "",
    "kis": "76"
  }
];

// @benchmark Jojo

Object.values(obj.reduce((r,o) =>
  {
  r[o.name] ??= {};
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => r[o.name][k] ||= o[k]);
  return r;
  },{})); 

// @benchmark Alexander

 obj.reduce((r, item, obj) => {
          (obj = r.map.get(item.name)) ? 
          Object.keys(item).forEach(k => k !== 'name' && item[k] && (obj[k] = item[k])) :
          r.map.set(item.name, r.arr[r.arr.length] = item);
          return r;
        }, {arr: [], map: new Map}
      ).arr

</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```